# Symfony2 new sql query in controller

Tags: sql, database, symfony, controller

I want to select something from my database using SQL in controller.

I want to get from database all events from last 12 hours.

This is my controller code:

```
public function SendDailyReportAction(Request $request){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT * FROM MainCoreBundle:Event WHERE added_on >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)");
        $statement = $query->getResult();

        var_dump($statement);

        return $this->render('MainAdminBundle:Reports:index.html.twig');

    }
```

What I done wrong? What is the alternative for select all (*)?
And did I wrote good path to Entity?

ERROR:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '*'
```

**I RESOLVE IT LIKE THIS:**

```
 public function SendDailyReportAction(Request $request){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e FROM MainCoreBundle:Event e WHERE e.date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), 4, 'MONTH')");
        $statement = $query->getResult();

        var_dump($statement);

        return $this->render('MainAdminBundle:Reports:index.html.twig');

    }
```

**What I change:**

- DATE_SUB(NOW() to DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE()

and add as @Joël Salamin said an alias **e.**

Comment: Show us the error you have when executing your code

Comment: @Joël Salamin a add error to my question content

Comment: Try to change your query like that : `SELECT * FROM MainCoreBundle:Event WHERE...`

Comment: The same. I thing that problem is with *?

Comment: And what if you add an alias like that: `SELECT e FROM MainCoreBundle:Event e WHERE e.added_on...`?

Comment: Yes this is good but now I got problem with this line. DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR");

Comment: you're missing a parentheses before the `"` at the end of your query

Comment: I add it thanks. But still not work. But i got one idea.

Answer (score 3):

OK firstly I would recommend placing you DQL into a Repository class to keep you code neat. But to answer your question simply do the following:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $results = $qb->select('e')
                  ->from('MainCoreBundle:Event','e')
                  ->where('e.addedOn >= :datetime')
                  ->setParameter('datetime', new \DateTime('-12 hours'))
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getOneOrNullResult();

     return [compact('results')];
```

Comment: and added_on must be name from table? or entity?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query with some corrections:

```
...
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e FROM MainCoreBundle:Event e WHERE e.added_on >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)");
...
```

Hope this will help you.

PS: Have a look at that: [Doctrine - Querying for objects using Query Builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder). This can considerably help you to query your database using the power of Doctrine Query Builder.